# Spark can not read data from ORC format

Tags: apache-spark, hive, sqoop

I have used

`SELECT * FROM temp.students`

directly in hive, I got the data
but when I use

`spark.sql('SELECT * FROM temp.students').show()`

I do not see any data just the headers and look like the table have no data.

**this problem occure every hive table in orc formats.**

- spark version: version 2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78
- hive version: Hive 3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78

** I also noted that my sqoop can not export data from orc table too, it say ACCID ......(I do not remember) **

I used spark to query data from hive orc table but i got no data at all just the columns name.

Edit: Now my spark also can not read parquet table, I don't know why.